# Angular Pagination only showing first page

Tags: html, angular, typescript, pagination

I have an Angular page which displays all the events a person has registered for.
Its just an API call, which returns JSON & displays the data - this all works fine.

I'm trying to add pagination to it where it would display 6 items per page (of pagination) - which its displaying 6 items, but i have another 2 registrations & the 2nd page of pagination doesn't appear.
If i remove the pagination, then all 8 registrations get displayed fine.
(I know 8 registrations ain't much, but we have customers with over 30 registrations, hence wanting to add pagination).

this is what the screen looks like... i zoomed out to show all 6 items & most of the page. Pagination is only being added to "My event registrations"

[image]

this is the HTML of the view ~ pagination line 34\35

```
<div class="spinner-container" *ngIf="cntActiveDataRetrievals > 0">
    <app-spinner></app-spinner>
</div>
<div class="container pt-4">
    <div class="alert alert-primary" [appTranslate]="'WaitForRegistrationsToAppear'">Please note there can be a delay in
        processing your registrations.</div>
</div>

<div *ngIf="cntActiveDataRetrievals === 0">
    <!--<div class="container">
        <div class="page-header">
            <h1>My event registrations</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="alert alert-primary" [appTranslate]="'WaitForRegistrationsToAppear'">Please note there can be a delay in processing your registrations.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="separator"></div>-->

    <div *ngIf="errorMessage" class="container">
        <app-errormessage [serverErrorMessage]="error.message" [errorMessageTranslationKey]="error.localizationKey">
        </app-errormessage>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="page-header" style="padding-top: 0px;">
            <h1>My event registrations</h1>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!--<div class="container" *ngIf="!registrations || registrations.length == 0 && !anyEventRegistrations">
        <div class="myRegistrations"><span [appTranslate]="'NoRegistrationsFound'">No registrations found</span></div>
    </div>-->

    <div class="container" *ngIf="registrations && registrations.length > 0 && anyEventRegistrations; else notEvent">
        <ngb-pagination [collectionSize]="registrations.length" [(page)]="page"></ngb-pagination>
        <ng-template ngFor let-i="index" let-registration [ngForOf]="registrations | slice: (page-1) * pageSize : (page-1) * pageSize + pageSize">
            <div *ngIf="registration.eventtype != '280260002'">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body" id="cardId">
                        <div class="d-flex display-button">
                            <div class="set-min-width">
                                <div class="w-100 justify-content-between">
                                    <div class="mb-1">
                                        <h2 class="text-truncate h5">
                                            <span class="mr-2">{{ registration.event }}</span>
                                            <span class="h6">
                                                <span
                                                    *ngIf="registration.sessionRegistrations != null && registration.sessionRegistrations.length > 0"><button
                                                        class="badge badge-primary badge-pill showMore"
                                                        data-toggle="collapse" [attr.id]="'heading' + i"
                                                        [attr.data-target]="'#collapse' + i" aria-expanded="false"
                                                        [attr.aria-controls]="'collapse' + i">show
                                                        sessions</button></span>
                                            </span>
                                        </h2>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <label class="mb-0 text-truncate set-max-width"><b>Event Date:</b> {{
                                            formatDate(registration.eventstartdate) }}</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <label class="mb-0 text-truncate set-max-width"><b>Name:</b> {{
                                            registration.contact }}</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <label class="mb-0 text-truncate set-max-width"><b>Email: </b>{{
                                            registration.email }}</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div *ngIf="registration.pass != ''">
                                        <label class="mb-1"><b>Ticket:</b> {{ registration.pass }}</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <label class="mb-0 text-truncate set-max-width"
                                            style="margin-bottom: 0rem;"><b>Invoice: </b>
                                            <!--<b [appTranslate]="'Invoice'">Invoice</b><b class="mr-1">:</b>
                                            <a [routerLink]="['/invoices']" [appTranslate]="'View invoice'">View invoice</a>-->
                                            <a href="/my-invoices" [appTranslate]="'View invoice'">View invoice</a>
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <label class="mb-0"><b>Registered on:</b> {{ formatDate(registration.createdon)
                                            }}</label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="ml-auto align-self-center button-large">
                                <div *ngIf="eventCloseDate(registration)" class="mb-1">
                                    <!--<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger button-large btn-block" [routerLink]="['/create-case','280260000',registration.id,registration.event]" [queryParams]="{casetypecode: 280260000, registrationId: registration.id, eventId: registration.event}" [appTranslate]="'Transfer'">Transfer</button>-->
                                    <a href="mailto:events@ceda.com.au?subject=Please transfer my registration for {{registration.event}}"
                                        class="btn btn-danger button-large btn-block" role="button">Transfer</a>
                                </div>
                                <div *ngIf="finalRefundDate(registration)" class="mb-2">
                                    <!--<button type="button" id="cancelButton-{{i}}" (click)="open(registration, i)" class="btn btn-danger button-large cancel_btn" [appTranslate]="'Cancel'">Cancel</button>-->
                                    <a href="mailto:events@ceda.com.au?subject=Please cancel my registration for {{registration.event}}"
                                        class="btn btn-danger button-large btn-block" role="button">Cancel</a>
                                </div>
                                <div *ngIf="cantCancelReg(registration)">
                                    <button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#cancelModal"
                                        (click)="onClickData(registration)"
                                        class="btn btn-danger button-large btn-block">Cancel</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div [attr.id]="'collapse' + i" class="collapse" [attr.aria-labelledby]="'heading' + i"
                        data-parent="#cardId"
                        *ngIf="registration.sessionRegistrations != null && registration.sessionRegistrations.length > 0">
                        <div class="card-body border-light">
                            <div *ngFor="let sessionRegistration of registration.sessionRegistrations">
                                <div class="d-flex display-button">
                                    <div class="set-min-width">
                                        <div class="w-100 justify-content-between">
                                            <div class="">
                                                <label class="mb-0 text-truncate set-max-width"><b>Session:
                                                    </b>{{sessionRegistration.sessionName}}</label>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="">
                                                <label class="mb-0 text-truncate set-max-width"><b>Date:
                                                    </b>{{formatDate(sessionRegistration.sessionstart) }} to
                                                    {{formatTime(sessionRegistration.sessionend) }}</label>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="ml-auto align-self-center">
                                        <div *ngIf="eventCloseDate(registration)" class="mb-1">
                                            <a href="mailto:events@ceda.com.au?subject=Please transfer my session registration for {{sessionRegistration.sessionName}}"
                                                class="btn btn-danger btn-sm btn-block" role="button">Transfer</a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div *ngIf="finalRefundDate(registration)" class="mb-2">
                                            <a href="mailto:events@ceda.com.au?subject=Please cancel my session registration for {{sessionRegistration.sessionName}}"
                                                class="btn btn-danger btn-sm btn-block" role="button">Cancel</a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div *ngIf="cantCancelReg(registration)" class="mb-2">
                                            <button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#sessionModal"
                                                (click)="onSessionClickData(registration, sessionRegistration)"
                                                class="btn btn-danger btn-sm btn-block">Cancel</button>
                                            <!--<button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#cancelModal" (click)="onClickData(registration)" class="btn btn-danger button-large btn-block">Cancel</button>-->
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!--<div class="flex-column align-items-start" *ngFor="let sessionRegistration of registration.sessionRegistrations"> 
                                    <div class="d-flex">
                                        <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
                                            <label class="mb-0 text-truncate set-max-width"><b>Session: </b>
                                            {{sessionRegistration.sessionName}}
                                            </label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="ml-auto align-self-center">
                                            <a href="mailto:events@ceda.com.au?subject=Please cancel my registration for {{sessionRegistration.sessionName}}" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm btn-block" role="button">Cancel</a>    
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="ml-auto align-self-center">
                                            <a href="mailto:events@ceda.com.au?subject=Please transger my reg..." class="btn btn-danger btn-sm btn-block" role="button">Transfer</a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <label class="mb-0 text-truncate set-max-width"><b>Date: </b>{{formatSessionStartDate(sessionRegistration.sessionstart) }} to {{formatSessionEndDate(sessionRegistration.sessionend) }}</label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>-->

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" id="cancelModal" role="dialog"
                        aria-labelledby="cancelModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <h4 class="modal-title">Cancel registration</h4>
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                    <p>Are you sure you want to cancel your registration for {{ registrationData ?
                                        registrationData.event : '' }}?</p>
                                    <p>Cancellation for this event closed on {{ registrationData ?
                                        formatDateNoTime(registrationData.ceda_finalrefundsdate) : '' }}. At this stage
                                        we are unable to offer a refund or credit for any cancellation. You can transfer
                                        your registration at any time. If you do not wish to continue please close this
                                        window, or continue by clicking one of the buttons below.</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col align-self-start">
                                            <a href="mailto:events@ceda.com.au?subject=Please transfer my registration for {{ registrationData ? registrationData.event : '' }}"
                                                role="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Transfer</a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col align-self-end">
                                            <a href="mailto:events@ceda.com.au?subject=Please cancel my registration for {{ registrationData ? registrationData.event : '' }}"
                                                role="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-block">Cancel</a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" id="sessionModal" role="dialog"
                        aria-labelledby="sessionModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <h4 class="modal-title">Cancel registration</h4>
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                    <p>Are you sure you want to cancel your registration for {{ sessionData ?
                                        sessionData.sessionName : '' }}?</p>
                                    <p>Cancellation for this event closed on {{ registrationData ?
                                        formatDateNoTime(registrationData.ceda_finalrefundsdate) : '' }}. At this stage
                                        we are unable to offer a refund or credit for any cancellation. You can transfer
                                        your registration at any time. If you do not wish to continue please close this
                                        window, or continue by clicking one of the buttons below.</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col align-self-start">
                                            <a href="mailto:events@ceda.com.au?subject=Please transfer my session registration for {{ sessionData ? sessionData.sessionName : '' }}"
                                                role="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Transfer</a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col align-self-end">
                                            <a href="mailto:events@ceda.com.au?subject=Please cancel my session registration for {{ sessionData ? sessionData.sessionName : '' }}"
                                                role="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-block">Cancel</a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <ng-template #notEvent>
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="MyRegistrations">No event registrations found</div>
                </div>
            </ng-template>
        </ng-template>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="page-header">
            <h1>My course enrolments</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="separator"></div>
    <div class="container" *ngIf="registrations && registrations.length > 0 && anyCourseRegistration; else notLearning">
        <ng-template ngFor let-i="index" let-registration [ngForOf]="registrations">
            <div *ngIf="registration.eventtype == '280260002'">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="d-flex display-button">
                            <div class="set-min-width">
                                <div class="w-100 justify-content-between">
                                    <div class="mb-1">
                                        <h2 class="text-truncate h5">
                                            <span class="mr-2">{{ registration.event }}</span>
                                        </h2>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <label class="mb-0 text-truncate set-max-width"><b>Name:</b> {{
                                            registration.contact }}</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <label class="mb-0 text-truncate set-max-width"><b>Email: </b>{{
                                            registration.email }}</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div *ngIf="registration.pass != ''">
                                        <label class="mb-0 text-truncate set-max-width"><b>Enrolment type:</b> {{
                                            registration.pass }}</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <label class="mb-0 text-truncate set-max-width"><b>Enroled on:</b> {{
                                            formatDate(registration.createdon) }}</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <label class="mb-0 text-truncate set-max-width"><b>Enrolment status: </b> {{
                                            enrollstatus(registration.coursestatus) }}</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <label class="mb-0 text-truncate set-max-width"><b>Invoice: </b>
                                            <!--<b [appTranslate]="'Invoice'">Invoice</b><b class="mr-1">:</b>
                                        <a [routerLink]="['/invoices']" [appTranslate]="'View invoice'">View invoice</a>-->
                                            <a href="/my-invoices" [appTranslate]="'View invoice'">View invoice</a>
                                        </label>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!--  Currently no buttons should be displayed for course registration.  leaving here should requirement change  -->
                            <!--<div class="ml-auto align-self-center button-large">
                            <div *ngIf="finalRefundDate(registration)" class="mb-2">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger button-large btn-block" [routerLink]="['/create-case','280260000',registration.id,registration.event]" [queryParams]="{casetypecode: 280260000, registrationId: registration.id, eventId: registration.event}" [appTranslate]="'Transfer'">Transfer</button>
                            </div>
                            <div *ngIf="eventCloseDate(registration)">
                                <a href="mailto:events@ceda.com.au?subject=Please cancel my registration for {{registration.event}}" class="btn btn-danger button-large btn-block" role="button">Cancel</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>-->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <ng-template #notLearning>
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="MyRegistrations">No enrollments found</div>
                </div>
            </ng-template>
        </ng-template>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="page-header">
            <h1 [appTranslate]="'MyWaitlistItems'">My waitlist items</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="separator"></div>

    <div class="container pb-4" *ngIf="!waitlistItems || waitlistItems.length == 0">
        <div class="myRegistrations"><span [appTranslate]="'NoWaitlistItemsFound'">No waitlist items found</span></div>
    </div>

    <div class="container" *ngIf="waitlistItems && waitlistItems.length > 0">
        <div *ngFor="let waitlistItem of waitlistItems">
            <app-waitlist-item-card [waitlistItem]="waitlistItem"></app-waitlist-item-card>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the Typescript - only including what i though relevant rather than whole component.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-myregistrations',
  templateUrl: './myregistrations.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./myregistrations.component.scss']
})
export class MyRegistrationsComponent implements OnInit {
    public cntActiveDataRetrievals = 0;
    public error: Error;
    private modalRef: NgbModalRef;
    public closedDate = null;
    public currentDateTime = null;
    public finalRefundsDate = null;
    public eventsCloseDate = null;
    //createdon : Date = new Date();
    public contactid : string; 
    user: User;
    public anyEventRegistrations:boolean = false;   //are there any Event Registrations
    public anyCourseRegistration:boolean = false;   //are there any CEDA Learning registrations
    public registrationData: any;                   //current registration - used for Modal.
    public sessionData: any;                        //current session registration - used for Session Modal.

    active = 1;
    pageSize = 6;
    page=1;

    registrations: MyRegistration[];
    waitlistItems: WaitlistItem[];

    constructor(@Inject(USER_SERVICE) private userService: UserService, 
    private modalService: NgbModal,
    private router: Router,
        private datePipe: DatePipe) {        
 }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadRegistrationsForUser();
    this.loadWaitlistItemsForUser();
  }

  private loadRegistrationsForUser(): void {
    this.cntActiveDataRetrievals += 1;

    this.userService.getLoggedInUser().subscribe( user => {
      this.contactid = user.id;
    });

    this.userService.getMyRegistrationsForUser(this.contactid).subscribe(registrations => {
      this.registrations = registrations;
      this.cntActiveDataRetrievals -= 1;

      if (this.registrations.filter(item => item.eventtype == '280260002'))
        this.anyCourseRegistration = true;
      if (this.registrations.filter(item => item.eventtype != '280260002'))
        this.anyEventRegistrations = true;
      
    }, (error: LocalizableError) => this.handleErrorResponse(error));
  }

  private loadWaitlistItemsForUser(): void {
    this.cntActiveDataRetrievals += 1;
    this.userService.getWaitlistItemsForUser().subscribe(waitlistItems => {
        this.waitlistItems = waitlistItems;
        this.cntActiveDataRetrievals -= 1;
    }, (error: LocalizableError) => this.handleErrorResponse(error)
    );
  }
```

Comment: I feel you forgot add the `[pageSize]="pageSize"` to the tag ngb-pagination: `<ngb-pagination [collectionSize]="registrations.length" [pageSize]="pageSize" [(page)]="page"></ngb-pagination>`